# XSLT sum concatenated instead of summed

Tags: xslt

I have the following input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <carac NAME="aaa" NOT="10"/>
        <value VAL="1"/>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <carac NAME="aaa" NOT="10"/>
        <value VAL="2"/>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <carac NAME="aaa" NOT="20"/>
        <value VAL="3"/>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <carac NAME="aaa" NOT="10"/>
        <value VAL="4"/>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <carac NAME="bbb" NOT="30"/>
        <value VAL="5"/>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <carac NAME="bbb" NOT="30"/>
        <value VAL="6"/>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <carac NAME="ccc" NOT="40"/>
        <value VAL="7"/>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <carac NAME="ccc" NOT="50"/>
        <value VAL="8"/>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

and I want to get for every different NAME the sum of all the different NOT, so if for the same NAME the NOT is repeated, it has to be summed only once.

The output for this example has to be: `aaa30 bbb30 ccc90`

My XSL looks like this, but instead of giving the result I want is showing `aaa1020 bbb30 ccc4050`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name="nameList" match="catalog/cd/carac" use="@NAME"/>
<xsl:key name="notList" match="catalog/cd/carac" use="concat(@NAME,'_',@NOT)"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="//carac[generate-id()=generate-id(key('nameList', @NAME)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="./@NAME"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lines">
            <xsl:for-each select="//carac[generate-id()=generate-id(key('notList',concat($name,'_',@NOT))[1])]">
                <noti>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@NOT"/>
                </noti>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum($lines)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="nameList" match="catalog/cd/carac" use="@NAME"/>
<xsl:key name="notList" match="catalog/cd/carac" use="concat(@NAME, '_', @NOT)"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html> 
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="cd/carac[generate-id()=generate-id(key('nameList', @NAME)[1])]">
                <xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>
                <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('nameList', @NAME)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="sum($current-group[generate-id()=generate-id(key('notList', concat(@NAME, '_', @NOT))[1])]/@NOT)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Any idea of why the one I wrote is not working as I expected?

Comment: I don't know why it works at all. You should have got an error, because you're trying to sum a *result-tree-fragment*, without converting it to a *node-set* first. That's in XSLT 1.0. If you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor (or an XSLT 1.0 processor that doesn't mind processing a RTF), then you should have done `<xsl:value-of select="sum($lines/noti)"/>`. Otherwise you're summing the text values of the `$lines` variable - of which there's only one, and it contains the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate about the result-tree-fragment but your answer totally works for what I need